# How to click on this 'Delete button' that comes as a alert small box

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

[How can i click on this delete button using Python and selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elkpk.png)

I have taken X-path of the delete button but it is not able to click on it .

Can anyone help me

[I have taken xpath but it is not able to click on it and this is the error i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orAc6.png)

[Here is the locator i have attached of the delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NlnJ.png)

Comment: can you provide the code snippet with xpath which you use?

Comment: What does this error tell you? Element not found. Maybe you need to transfer the selenium focus to this window, if it is an iframe. And there are several other options. If you type this error into a search engine, then you will get a lot of solutions, even on this SO.

Comment: Driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/div/div[6]/button[1]').click() @Vova